# Can we hookup approval process to KIE Drools Workbench rule updates?

Tags: drools, jbpm, business-rules, drools-guvnor, kie

I am using KIE Drools Workbench to manage Business Rules.
I want to know is there a way to hookup Approval Process for Rule updates in Workbench.

For Ex: If an analyst updated some rule in .drl or decision table and saved it then I want to go this change into Managers approval queue and once manager approved it then only that rule update should become live.

Is it possible to achieve this through Drools only? Or do we need to use JBPM kind of things for this?

Comment: Curious - did you implement a solution?  We are looking into the same thing.

Comment: No. Actually KIE Drools Workbench is giving more and more problems. For the no. of rules that we might have it seems like using Drools itself is overkill. So it's on hold!

Comment: I have same requirement, is there any solution for it.